# How to setup Gitlab hook to validate a git push to remote

Tags: linux, git, bash, gitlab, devops

We have a DevOps process where people checkout or update from the remote master branch, create a new local working branch from the master and begin work in the local branch.

1) I need to put in restrictions that will keep people from pushing straight to the remote master branch directly. Instead, people need to push changes to their local branches to the same branch on the remote, after which an admin or code reviewer will merge it into the remote master.

2) I need a hook that will ensure that there is a valid Gitlab ticket or issue number in the form, say for example #PROJECTNAME123 before allowing their push to proceed to their remote branches (prior to code review and merging into remote master). Additionally, they must not be able to push if the ticket does not exist or is not yet open.

I have already created a Bash pre-receive hook using information from both the following websites but they get called but still allow the git push to get to the server even when I do not pass a Gitlab ticket/issue number.

https://github.com/Praqma/git-hooks/commit/2aa087fada0b0da51724f37a902362ddd78e168f

http://blog.hgomez.net/2015/03/02/Gitlab-custom-hooks-Bash-Way.html

The following is the pre-receive script and a bash function script that it calls.

pre-receive (No extension)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

source /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Product-common/ProductCommonParent.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive-functions.sh

# enforced custom commit message format
while read old_revision new_revision refname ; do
        process_revision
done

exit 0
```

pre-receive-functions.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#


regexp="#[0-9]\+"

grep_msg()
{
        grepped=$( echo $message | grep -i $regexp )
}

process_revision ()
{
  #revisions=$(git rev-list $old_revision..$new_revision)
echo "In pre-receive hook. Just before retrieving the revisions"
if [ "$old_revision" -eq 0 ]; then
    # list everything reachable from new_revision but not any heads
   revisions=$(git rev-list $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/* | sed 's/^/\^/') $new_revision)
else
   revisions=$(git rev-list $old_revision..$new_revision)
fi

echo "In pre-receive hook. Just before IFS"
  IFS='\n' read -ra array <<< "$revisions"
  for rid in "${!array[@]}"; do
        revision=${array[rid]}
    message=$(git cat-file commit $revision | sed '1,/^$/d')
        grepped=$(echo $message | grep -i "#[0-9]\+")
    grep_msg()
    if [ -z "$grepped" ] ; then
                grepped_none=$(echo $message | grep -i "#none")
                if [ -n "$grepped_none" ] ; then
                        echo "Warning, you are committing without a ticket reference" >&1
                else
                        echo "You have not included a ticket reference" >&2
                        exit 1
                fi
    fi
  done


}
```

The following is the output when I try to push (I am pushing from a Git Bash shell on Windows 8.1 to a Fedora Core 24 having Gitlab installed):

```
xxx@xxxxx-HP MINGW64 ~/Documents/DevOps Re-Engineering/ProductCommonParent (ProductCommonParent002)
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 369 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: In pre-receive hook. Just before retrieving the revisions
remote: In pre-receive hook. Just before IFS
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for ProductCommonParent002, visit:
remote:   http://localhost/Product-common/ProductCommonParent/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=ProductCommonParent002
remote:
To http://192.168.56.101/Product-common/ProductCommonParent.git
 * [new branch]      ProductCommonParent002 -> ProductCommonParent002
```

Note: Gitlab and its dependencies, including git, are installed on the same Fedora Core 24 Linux System.

I will appreciate speedy help in getting past this. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Restrictions are already available by default for every default restricted branch of any new project or git repo. These restrictions apply to non-admin and non-root users of Gitlab.

2) We implemented the rules for checking that our developers comply with our development policies and processes by writing a Java spring boot CommandLineRunner application that called the Gitlab API. This application was packaged as a jar file.

We ensured that a developer must have a valid ticket number as part of his git commit message before he/she can push successfully to the remote counterpart of his working branch. This valid ticket must be assigned to him, have a valid milestone, and have the right label (either of NEW FEATURE, BUG, TASK etc.) selected for the push to be successful.

We integrated with the git hooks on the Gitlab Server by using a bash shell script that executed the jar file and allowed or failed the push request based on the output from the java application. This shell script, which is an adaptation of http://blog.hgomez.net/2015/03/02/Gitlab-custom-hooks-Bash-Way.html, can be found below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# pre-receive hook for Commit Check
#
COMPANY_EMAIL="mycorp.org"

readonly PROGNAME=$(basename $0)
readonly PROGDIR=$(readlink -m $(dirname $0))
IS_MERGE=0

check_single_commit()
{
  COMMIT_CHECK_STATUS=1
    echo "Repo >> $REPOSITORY_BASENAME"

    if [[ "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" == "Merge branch"* ]]; then
      COMMIT_CHECK_STATUS=0
      IS_MERGE=1
    else
    workFlowResult=`java -jar -Dspring.config.location=/home/gitlab/gitlab_custom_hooks/application.properties /home/gitlab/gitlab_custom_hooks/gitlab-tool.jar -prercv "$COMMIT_AUTHOR" "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" "$REPOSITORY_BASENAME"`
    echo "COMMIT_AUTHOR=$COMMIT_AUTHOR, COMMIT_MESSAGE=$COMMIT_MESSAGE, REPOSITORY_BASE=$REPOSITORY_BASENAME"

      echo " >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $workFlowResult >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" >&2
    if [[ "$workFlowResult" == *"PRE_RECEIVE_OK"* ]]; then
      echo " >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $workFlowResult >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" >&2
      COMMIT_CHECK_STATUS=0
    fi

    fi
}

check_all_commits()
{
  REVISIONS=$(git rev-list $OLD_REVISION..$NEW_REVISION)
  IFS='\n' read -ra LIST_OF_REVISIONS <<< "$REVISIONS"
if [ $(git rev-parse --is-bare-repository) = true ]
then
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
else
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename $(readlink -nf "$PWD"/..))
fi
    echo REPOSITORY_BASENAME is $REPOSITORY_BASENAME
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=${REPOSITORY_BASENAME%.git}

  for rid in "${!LIST_OF_REVISIONS[@]}"; do
    REVISION=${LIST_OF_REVISIONS[rid]}
    COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git cat-file commit $REVISION | sed '1,/^$/d')
    COMMIT_AUTHOR=$(git cat-file commit $REVISION | grep committer | sed 's/^.* \([^@ ]\+@[^ ]\+\) \?.*$/\1/' | sed 's/<//' | sed 's/>//' | sed 's/@$COMPANY_EMAIL//')
    check_single_commit

    if [ "$COMMIT_CHECK_STATUS" != "0" ]; then
      echo "Commit validation failed for commit $REVISION" >&2
      exit 1
    fi

  done
}





# Get custom commit message format
while read OLD_REVISION NEW_REVISION REFNAME ; do
  check_all_commits
done

exit 0
```

3) Although not part of the question, integrating PMD checks at the Server-side without the use of a PMD Jenkins plugins, required the download of the PMD executable startup dependencies, the execution of PMD from within a python script to statically analyze source files being pushed by developers to the git server (Gitlab server). The python script that bootstraps PMD could be easily integrated into the above bash shell script. The python script, which is an adaptation of http://bluec0re.blogspot.com.ng/2012/05/git-pre-receive-hook-with-checkstyle.html, can be found below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
import shutil
import os
import errno

# variables for checkstyle
#checkstyle = '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/product-common/ProductCommonParent.git/custom_hooks/checkstyle-7.5.1-all.jar'
#checkstyle_config = '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/product-common/ProductCommonParent.git/custom_hooks/sun_checks.xml'
pmd = '/home/gitlab/gitlab_custom_hooks/pmd-bin-5.5.4/bin/run.sh'

# implementing check_output for python < 2.7
if not hasattr(subprocess, 'check_output'):
    def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
        if 'stdout' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
        process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
        output, unused_err = process.communicate()
        retcode = process.poll()
        if retcode:
            cmd = kwargs.get("args")
            if cmd is None:
                cmd = popenargs[0]
            er = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
            er.output = output
            raise er
        return output
    subprocess.check_output = check_output


# helper for calling executables
def call(*args, **kwargs):
    return subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs).strip()


# helper for calling git
def call_git(cmd, *args, **kwargs):
    return call(['git'] + cmd, *args, **kwargs)


# get all new commits from stdin
def get_commits():
    commits = {}
    for line in sys.stdin:
        old, new, ref = line.strip().split(' ')
        if old == '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000':
            old = '4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904'

        if ref not in commits:
            commits[ref] = []
        commits[ref].append({
            'old': old,
            'new': new,
            'files': get_changed_files(old, new)
            })

    return commits


# get a list of changed files between to commits
def get_changed_files(old, new):
    return call_git(['diff', '--name-only', old, new]).split('\n')


# get filemode, object type (blob,tree,commit), hash for the given file at the
# given commit
def get_change_type(commit, filename):
    return call_git(['ls-tree', commit, filename]).split('\t')[0].split(' ')


commits = get_commits()

# use the latest file commit only
print "Cleaning up file list..."

files = {}
count = 0
for ref, data in commits.iteritems():
    files[ref] = {}
    for commit in data:
        for filename in commit['files']:
            if not filename.lower().endswith('.java'): continue
            files[ref][filename] = get_change_type(commit['new'], filename)
    count += len(files[ref])

print "%d Files to check in %d branches" % (count, len(files))

# create temporary dir and save a copy of the new files
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp('git_hook')
for ref, files in files.iteritems():
    for filename, data in files.iteritems():
        dname = os.path.dirname(filename)
        bname = os.path.basename(filename)
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(tempdir, dname))
        except OSError, exc:
            if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST:  # directory exists already
                pass
            else:
                raise

        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, dname, bname), 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(call_git(['cat-file', data[1], data[2]]))

try:
    # call checkstyle and/or pmd and print output
    # print call(['java', '-jar', checkstyle, '-c', checkstyle_config, tempdir])
    # print call(['java', '-jar', '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/product-common/ProductCommonParent.git/custom_hooks/hooks-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', '-prercv', '79', 'developer-email-id', "I am now done with issue #500 #501 #502"])
    print call([pmd, 'pmd', '-d', tempdir, '-f', 'text', '-R', 'rulesets/java/basic.xml,rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml,rulesets/java/imports.xml,rulesets/java/strings.xml,rulesets/java/braces.xml,rulesets/java/clone.xml,rulesets/java/design.xml,rulesets/java/clone.xml,rulesets/java/finalizers.xml,rulesets/java/junit.xml,rulesets/java/migrating.xml,rulesets/java/optimizations.xml,rulesets/java/strictexception.xml,rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml,rulesets/java/typeresolution.xml'])
    print "SUCCESS"
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, ex:
    print ex.output  # print checkstyle and/or pmd messages
    exit(1)
finally:
    # remove temporary directory
    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
```